# How to run and hide using Batch File?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to run a script (`MouseParty.pie`) using [`Glovepie`](http://glovepie.org/glovepie.php).

This is my batch file script; it runs `MouseParty` on the `GlovePIE IDE`.

```
.\\glovepie.exe -MouseParty
```

The only problem is I need to hide the `GlovePIE IDE`. Any ideas how I can do that.
Also, I would appreciate if you can tell me how to run MouseParty when it's in another folder than the batch file.

If you have any other ideas to run this other than using a batch file, I'd be open to any suggestions with other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide a window is more advanced than a simple batch script can handle. I suggest something such as [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) which is made for automating UI components. This can be done with something as simple as:

```
Run, notepad.exe
WinWait, Untitled - Notepad
Sleep, 500
WinHide ; use the window found above
```

As for another directory, you would just pass the full path such as:

```
c:\glovepie\glovepie.exe -MouseParty
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use VBScript

```
Set wss=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wss.Rnn 'notepad.exe', 0
```

Comment: I got it working on the batch file but thanks for the answer anyway. :D

Answer (score 2):

You could use the command `HidePie` also. This will hide `GlovePIE` to the taskbar and only be an icon. It will hide instantly when you place it anywhere [on its own line] that isn't inside a `If` or similar. If you put it inside an `If` command it will hide when that event is triggered.

**What I mean by inside a** `If` **command is it will not occur until that** `If` **statement is true.** Just trying to clarify that.